# Swift scrollToItem works when subclassed UICollectionViewController. But doesn't work with "has-a relation" collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on a UICollectionView which suppose to scroll up if keyboard is shown. Basically by calling following function.

```
  @objc func handleKeyboardShow() {
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: [0, messages.count - 1],
                                at: .bottom,
                                animated: false)
  }
```

I realised that above code is effective when I use UICollectionViewController.

```
class ChatViewController: UICollectionViewController {
...
}
```

But it doesn't work if I use collectionView like this.

```
class ChatViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

  private var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Everything works exactly the same but scrollToItem doesn't work. (not a crash nor error messages. just silently) I would like to go with the second approach. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that in the second case handleKeyboardShow isn't invoked at all? Did you put a breakpoint?

Comment: @ArikSegal Thank you for leaving a comment. I've put a print statement to make sure it is called. So, scrollToItem function is called but nothing happened.